# I am not able to add dropdownlist at first row of gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview

I have added gridview that is binds with csv file data that stored in session variable like this:

```
 dgData.DataSource = Session["csvdata"];
 dgData.DataBind();
```

It binds perfectly.But i need to add dropdownlist at first row of gridview for mapping of database column name with grid header.I used this code to add dropdownlist.But dropdown added to header instead of first row.

```
 protected void dgData_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
      if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header )
    {

        for (Int32 i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
            ddl.ID = "ddlCol" + i.ToString ();
            e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(ddl);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header you are adding to header. Shouldn't that be !=

Comment: @cheedep  how i can add to first row of grid..please any solution??

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void dgData_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DropDownList ddl;
            if (e.Row.RowIndex == 0)
            {
                for (Int32 i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
                {
                    ddl = new DropDownList();
                    ddl.ID = "ddlCol" + i.ToString ();
                    e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(ddl);
                }
            }
       }
}
```

this code add's control to exatly first row of grid-view